# CheckValidity() on a single field in the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue about `CheckValidity()`. I have a form with two buttons, one has one field required (check), the other 2 (add).

```
<form id="form" name="form">

    <input required type="text" name="test1" id="test1" class="testfields"value = "<?php echo (isset($checkTEST))?$checkTEST:'';?>"> <p></p>
    <input required type="text" name="test2" id="test2" class="testfields" value = "<?php echo (isset($checkTEST2))?$checkTEST2:'';?>"> <p></p>

    <div id="checkbutton">      
        <button id="Check" name="check" class="submitter" >Check</button>
    </div>  
    <div id="addbutton">
        <button id="Add" name="add" class="submitter">Add</button>
    </div>  
</form>

$(".submitter").click(function(e){                 
    if(e.target.id !== "Check")
    {
        if($("#form")[0].checkValidity())
        {
            formSubmitted(this.name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($("#form")[0][1].checkValidity())
        {
            formSubmitted(this.name);
        }
    }

});
```

For the add part it works fine, and for the check part, the behavior is correct too (form submitted or not if field filled or not), but I still have the "Please fill out this field" on the second field. Why is that?

Comment: `$("#form")[0][1]`  Should that be `$("#form")[1]`?  Or maybe the first one should be `$("#form")[0][0]`?  Either way, they should probably both have the same depth of indexes, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what your form is supossed to do? You only have two buttons and also I don't see any required attribute in your form?

Comment: @xander sorry I forgot a part of the code, I add it.

Comment: @AnaTechno Could you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @PatrickQ I used debug to write $("#form")[0][1], and it really seems to work, but I am just annoyed by the error message on the second field, that makes the code look it's not working. What is a fiddle? :)

Comment: Click the link in my comment